# How to rewrite URL in codeigniter with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

How can I rewrite a URL from

```
http://website.com/index.php/content/index/3
```

to

```
http://website.com/content/3
```

in the `.htaccess` file?

I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php/$1/index/$2 [L]
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I have try this "RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php/$1/index/$2 [L]" but it doesn't work.

Comment: I've added your comment to the question. You can further improve it by explaining what exactly didn't work: what happened? What did you think should happen?

Answer (score 1):

create .htaccess file in project root directory if other .htaccess file is not already created.
copy paste below codes into it .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projectname
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following pattern :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php/$1/index/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following Stuff:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
 #Send request via index.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```